# How can I change the color of the hamburger in bootstrap 4 from the given link

Tags: javascript, html, css

From this given link. the example is given.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

Comment: What happened Web Developers???

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

This hamburger icon is a svg background color

You can set your color : stroke='rgba(255,0,0, 1)

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,0,0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

It will look like...
[image]

Comment: @Izzatullo Kanoatov : check this

Comment: I should add only the background-image. Then it will work?

Comment: I forget to add class ".navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon" ! if you will add background image with this code and you can set your color  with rgba value.

this icon is an image(svg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need some css here.

```
<style>
button#navbar-toggler {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This hamburger icon is a svg background color

You can set your color : stroke='rgba(255,0,0, 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `background` of the icon.  Here is how you would do it in your example:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon{
background: red;
}
```

See image:
[image]

Comment: It is not what I am asking for.

Comment: Well maybe try to be more specific.  You said change the color of the hamburger, and it looks like that's what I did.  Sorry if it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided, the three lines that represent the hamburger are an image, so you can change these unless you code the three lines in. 
The only bit you can change the color to is the border, for eaxmple:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
```

[image]